# The docker image on Mac OS requires access to /mnt

Tags: docker, macos

I'm trying to start a container and docker throws an error

> docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:  The path /mnt is
> not shared from the host and is not known to Docker. You can configure
> shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File
> Sharing. I use Mac OS, and this directory is not used here

I tried to set the settings in Docker - resources - file sharing directory / mnt but the settings are not saved. I tried to create this directory, it didn't work either

i use shell script

Comment: What command are you running? Please update the question with any additional information.

Comment: Is this a public container from e.g. dockerhub? If it is, it would make it easy for anyone on a macOS system with Docker to test.